# Kohana/PHP - Retrieving items based on user applied filter

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3.3

My website is Q&A site like stackoverflow.com. When a user creates a question he have the ability to attach some tags to it. Later, when he need to find all questions which belongs to a category, he can use the filter box which accepts tag names. based on user entries i will just refresh the job list.

My table design is like below

Table: Questions

### id | QuestionTitle |Other details.....|

1 | Why is earth round? |.............|

2 |How much is moon's diameter?|......|

Table: Tags

### id | tagname

1 | planets

2 | earth

3 | moon

Table: AttachedTags

id | question_id | tag_id

1 | 1            |2

2 | 1            |1

3 | 2            |3

In the PHP/Controller i will get tag id's as user input's in the filter box.

What is the best method to fetch all those questions under a particular tag.

I am using PHP and Kohana 3.3

Comment: possible duplicate of [Applying filter using SQL Join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27342157/applying-filter-using-sql-join)

Answer (score 0):

try joining your tables as shown, join both tables based on question id

```
select q.id,q.title
from questions q inner join attachedtags at on (q.id = at.question_id) where at.tag_id = ur-passed-tag-id
```

Comment: please add some explanation to your answer, showing what the code does and how it solves the problem. This will help others in the future