# Applying filter using SQL Join

Tags: php, sql

My website is a Q&A site like stackoverflow.com. When a user creates a question, he has the ability to tags it. Later, when he need to find all questions which belongs to a category, he can use the filter box which accepts tag names. Based on user entries, i will just refresh the job list.

My table design is like below

```
Table: Questions

id | QuestionTitle                |Other details|
----------------------------------|-------------|
1  | Why is earth round?          |
2  | How much is moon's diameter? |

Table: Tags

id | tagname 
----------------
1 | planets    
2 | earth    
3 | moon

Table: AttachedTags

id | question_id | tag_id
-------------------------    
1 | 1            |2    
2 | 1            |1    
3 | 2            |3
```

In the PHP/Controller i will get tag id's as user input's in the filter box.

What is the best method to fetch all those questions under a particular tag?

I have used the following query, but it is retrieving a job two times, because a job can have more than one category.

```
SELECT
    Questions.id,
    Questions.jobtitle,
    AttachedTags.tag_id 
FROM
    Questions INNER JOIN
    AttachedTags ON Questions.id = AttachedTags.question_id
WHERE
    AttachedTags.tag_id IN (1,2)
```

Comment: I don't see skill_id in the AttachedTags table's example...

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it enough to add a distinct to filter out duplications and remove tag_id from the select?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Questions.id,
    Questions.jobtitle
FROM
    Questions INNER JOIN
    AttachedTags ON Questions.id = AttachedTags.question_id
WHERE
    AttachedTags.tag_id IN (1,2)
```